# The $\mathcal{J}$- class of a primitive idempotent in a regular semigroup.

Tags: relations, semigroups

I am currently studying some basic facts of regular semigroups and Green's relations and I got stuck on the following exercise problem.

Let $S$ be a regular semigroup with a primitive idempotent $e$. Show, that
$J(e)$ is the least ideal of $S$.

I will appreciate any solutions or ideas. Thanks! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not true. Take the two-element monoid $\{1, 0\}$. Then $1$ is a primitive idempotent but the $\mathcal{J}$-class of $1$ is not even an ideal.

Comment: Thank you. Would the statement hold if semigroup $S$ had no zero?

Comment: If $S$ has no zero, then *primitive* means *minimal* for the natural order on idempotents. Thus the ideal generated by $e$ is now the $\mathcal{J}$-class of $e$ and this ideal is the unique minimal ideal of $S$.